# Google Chrome stutters when scrolling and other issues

Tags: debian, chrome

I have heavy problems with the Google Chrome Version for Debian. The same problems occur in Chromium, but not with Iceweasel.

When i scroll the page stutters and flickers instead of smoothly going upwards. On a Webapp i am currently develoing the fixed navbar that should stay on top of the screen when scrolling doesnt do so but then sometimes jumps down later staying there in the middle of the screen when I scroll back to the top.
I do not experience those issues on windows with chrome nor on an other browser on debian. I dont think its a problem with my laptop, here are my specs tho:

```
CPU:
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               1923.281
CPU max MHz:           2700,0000

RAM:
12GB
```

How can i solve this problem? As I synchronize my bookmarks and stuff via Chrome I am not really willed to swap back to Firefox.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? This started to appear for me a few weeks ago and I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a new tab and enter address `chrome://flags/`

Find Smooth Scrolling flag.

Click **Enable**

To **Restart** Chrome browser clic **relaunch now**

Comment: If enabling the smooth scrolling doesn't help, try disabling it. It helped me. Scrolling is less smooth now (d'uh), but at least the flickering is gone.

Answer (score 2):

As found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292180&p=13345177#post13345177); make sure Chrome at least *tries* to enable HW acceleration:

> Try the simplest fix first.
>
> Go into chrome://settings, click on show advanced settings at the bottom, and then scroll down to the bottom again and make sure "use hardware acceleration when available" is checked.

This was the problem in my situation.